# Python program that totals positive numbers only

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a program that only sums the total of the positive numbers entered. When the user enters a negative number the program stops but does not add that negative number to the sum. How do I get the program not to add the negative number to the sum? Here is what I have.

```
  # set parameters for user
  print('Enter a positive number then hit enter, When you want to end the 
  process enter a negative number')
  entered_number = 0
  value = 0

  # user enters numbers
  while entered_number >= 0:
      entered_number = int(input('Enter a number: '))
      value += entered_number

  # prints sum of numbers entered

  print('The total sum of the numbers you entered is', value)
```

My sum with the above code would be if I entered 2 , 2 , -1  is 3.
I would like the program's sum to be 4 if I entered 2, 2, -1.

Comment: OK, what's the problem you are facing?

Comment: I only want to add the positive number but when a user enters the negative number to stop the loop and sum the numbers entered it sums the negative number with the total. For example. user enters 2 , then 2 , the - 1 the sum comes up with 3 but should be 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop will add the negative number to the variable `value` because you don't terminate the loop before actually adding the entered (negative) number.

```
while entered_number >= 0:
    entered_number = int(input('Enter a positive number: '))
    value += entered_number # If entered_number is negative it will still
                            # be added, because the loop will terminate 
                            # after this iteration
```

**There are 2 solutions**:

1. Move the `value += entered_number` to before where you enter a new number

This way the loop will evaluate the entered number before adding it to the sum

```
while entered_number >= 0:
    value += entered_number
    entered_number = int(input('Enter a positive number: '))
```

2. Loop forever and break inside the loop instead

The logic is the same as in 1, just that we check differently.

```
while True:
    entered_number = int(input('Enter a positive number: '))
    if entered_number < 0:
        break
    value += entered_number # This line will only be reached if we
                            #  haven't breaked out from the loop
```

Comment: You were right I inferred the question and wasn't explicit. Thank you for reading between the lines.  I edited my original post. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: No problem @BrianMichaels :) I've edited my answer to not point it out as well. A great tip when asking questions is to give an example input and the resulting (faulty) output, and then specifying what you actually want the output to be. You can read more about it here: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)